# Nuxt.js on Google App Engine- 2 projects, one in root and another in directory

Tags: google-app-engine, nuxt.js, google-appengine-node

I have 2 nuxt projects- I want to run one at root directory- [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), and another at [www.example.com/admin](http://www.example.com/admin) on App Engine

Any ideas on how to setup the same?

Answer (score -1):

Did you gave a look to this official documentation about how to deploy on Google App Engine?

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/deployment/appengine-deployment

Comment: Yes, I have gone through the documentation. It doesn't mention how to handle multiple nuxt.js projects, one at root and another in sub-directory

Comment: @sanketpahuja why would you need 2 instances on the exact same domain name? Can't one be enough?

Comment: 1 project is the static website- we want running on abc.example.com, which and other has the main application screen for registered users-  we want running on abc.example.com/app

Comment: Does it justifies having 2 apps? Why not doing both in a single one? Less complexity and less expensive.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question. It should be a comment.

Comment: @lmonninger regarding the type of the question + the effort put in it, it should be closed anyway. I'm not gonna assume a whole configuration and write something that is already officially written.